# print key/value in thymeleaf from hashmap/arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap, thymeleaf

The code in java/springboot:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "results")
public String results(
        Model model, 
        @RequestParam String searchType,
        @RequestParam String searchTerm) {

    model.addAttribute("columns", ListController.columnChoices);
    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jobsbyval = JobData
            .findforValue(searchTerm);
    model.addAttribute("items", jobsbyval);
    return "search";
}
```

The code in html/thymeleaf:

```
<div>
  <table>
    <tbody>
      <tr th:each="item : ${items}">
        <!--each loop begins -->
        <td th:text="${item}"></td> //item.value or item.key dont work!!

      </tr>
      <!--loop ends -->
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Here is the html ouput.

```
{header 1=something, header 2=Analyst, category 3=somename, location=somewhere, skill=Stats}
```

The desired HTML output(key/value) in table format would be:

```
header 1  something  
header 2  Analyst 
category  somename 
location  somewhere 
skill Stats
```

Comment: Thank you very much in editing the code and outputting neatly. i tried numerous times to make it pretty in the editor, but didnt work. Thank you again!!

Answer (score 9):

Yes, it does not work because `items` (or `jobsbyval`) is not a map but it is a list of maps, namely: `ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> jobsbyval`.

Your thymeleaf snippet just prints the string representation of the first and only map within the list. If you need to iterate all maps within the list you need a nested loop, for example:

**Model**:

```
    List<Map<String, String>> mapsList = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>();

    Map<String, String> map1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map1.put("keyinmap1", "valueinmap1");
    Map<String, String> map2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map2.put("keyinmap2", "valueinmap2");

    mapsList.add(map1);
    mapsList.add(map2);

    modelMap.put("mapsList", mapsList);
```

**View**:

```
<div th:each="map : ${mapsList}">
     <div th:each="mapEntry : ${map}">
         <span th:text="${mapEntry.key}"></span> = 
         <span th:text="${mapEntry.value}"></span> 
     </div>
</div>
```

**Output**:

```
keyinmap1 = valueinmap1
keyinmap2 = valueinmap2
```

`th:each` accept maps, in this case:

> When iterating maps, iter variables will be of class
>   java.util.Map.Entry

For details - see [here](http://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/2.1/usingthymeleaf.html#iterable-values).