# Using HashMaps in a backing bean

Tags: java, spring-mvc, thymeleaf

I'm building a job search tracker for my job searches and I'm trying to use a HashMap to store an applicant's skill set in a backing bean and I'm having issues applying the HashMap to the form.

Here's the backing bean

```java
package com.nexus.jobsearchtracker.domain;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.persistence.Embedded;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.validation.constraints.NotNull;
import javax.validation.constraints.Size;

@Entity
@Table(name="Applicants")
public class Applicant {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 40)
    private String firstName;

    @NotNull
    @Size(max = 40)
    private String lastName;

    private Integer yearsOfExperience;

    @Embedded
    private Address address;

    private HashMap<String, Integer> skills = new HashMap<>();

    public Applicant() {}

    public Applicant(Long id, @NotNull @Size(max = 40) String firstName, @NotNull @Size(max = 40) String lastName,
            Integer yearsOfExperience, Address address, HashMap<String, Integer> skills) {
        super();
        this.id = id;
        this.firstName = firstName;
        this.lastName = lastName;
        this.yearsOfExperience = yearsOfExperience;
        this.address = address;
        this.skills = skills;
    }

    public HashMap<String, Integer> getSkills() {
        return skills;
    }

    public void setSkills(HashMap<String, Integer> skills) {
        this.skills = skills;
    }
        // Other accessors ommited for brevity
}
```

Here's the form I'm using

```html
<table>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>Skill</td>
            <td>Years Experience</td>
            <td><input id="addSkill" type="button" value="Add Skill"></td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="skillset">
        <tr>
            <td><input id="skill" type="text" th:field="*{skills[key]}"></td>
            <td><input id="yearsExp" type="number" th:field="*{skills[value]}"></td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

When I debug my code, I end up seeing

```
{value=11}
```

instead of

```
{java=11}
```

Is there something that I'm doing wrong here?

**Edit:** After doing some more research, I found the answer via Thymeleaf's preprocessors.

```html
<tbody id="skillset" th:each="skill,skillStat: *{skills}">
    <tr>
        <td><input id="skill" type="text" th:field="*{skills[__${skillStat.index}__].skill}"></td>
        <td><input id="yearsExp" type="number" th:field="*{skills[__${skillStat.index}__].yearsOfExperience}"></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

Thanks for the suggestions!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [print key/value in thymeleaf from hashmap/arraylist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42966653/print-key-value-in-thymeleaf-from-hashmap-arraylist)

Comment: What you want isn't possible. The inputs `skills[key]` and `skills[value]` don't somehow combine to create a single HashMap entry, instead you are doing the equivalent of setting `map.put("key", valueFromKeyInput)` and `map.put("value", valueFromValueInput)`